# How can Opera 47.0+ on Linux play Netflix videos?

Tags: opera

Netflix.com can stream video on Google Chrome, Firefox, and Chromium (with chromium-widevine package installed). How can Opera (64bit Linux) play Netflix videos?

Comment: I believe that writing your own question and answering it immediately is frowned upon here.

Comment: @SimonSheehan Shall I delete then? I thought this info. might be useful to someone else.

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly acceptable and even encouraged. See [here](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @SimonSheehan Oh I see now. It's `answering + accepting answer`. (Thanks to @n8te pointing that out with the link he provided.) So it's ok to post the answer as long as I don't accept it for 48 hours (in case someone comes up with something better).

Comment: Opera is generally superior to any other browser, even after the common unified UI implementation.

Comment: I can watch Netflix just fine with Opera on Ubuntu using the solution regarding libffmpeg.so on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1088367/how-can-i-watch-netflix-on-opera-via-the-built-in-vpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install google chrome. Chrome browser brings required libraries inside /opt/google/chrome/ directory (libwidevinecdmadapter.so and libwidevinecdm.so).
Then you need to check does your widevine_config.json in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/resources is fullfilled correctly. Example:

```
[
   {
      "preload" : "/opt/google/chrome/libwidevinecdm.so",
      "plugin" : "/opt/google/chrome/libwidevinecdmadapter.so"
   },
   {
      "preload" : "/opt/google/chrome-beta/libwidevinecdm.so",
      "plugin" : "/opt/google/chrome-beta/libwidevinecdmadapter.so"
   },
   {
      "preload" : "/opt/google/chrome-unstable/libwidevinecdm.so",
      "plugin" : "/opt/google/chrome-unstable/libwidevinecdmadapter.so"
   }
]
```

Last step:

> install a user-agent switcher.
>
> Make sure the user-agent string is up-to-date. Some user-agent switchers use out-of-date strings. This one works as of August 2017:
>
> > Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Install a user-agent switcher.

Make sure the user-agent string is up-to-date. Some user-agent switchers use out-of-date strings. This one works as of August 2017:

`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.90 Safari/537.36`

(via https://forum.voidlinux.eu/t/why-dont-chromium-firefox-have-any-screen-tearing/3200/4?u=da99)